# Javascript resizing CK Editor not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ckeditor

I am working with javascript ckEditor and I have an issue with resizing that has been mind bugling for the past few days. 
I have an angular object called ckEditorConfig where I store the config for my ckEditor. Currently I can see some properties being set (so I know it is working to some degree). However, when I try to resize my editor it does not resize to the level that I would like.

Here are a snippets of the of the html and js codes to add more light to what I am talking about:

- This is contained in my controller

  ```
  $scope.ckEditorConfig = {
      uiColor : '#FFFFFF',
      toolbarGroups: [
          { name: 'undo' }
      ],

      removeButtons: '',
      extraPlugins: 'font,sourcedialog,sourcearea,stylescombo,colorbutton, colordialog',
      contentsCss: '/path/to/css',
      customConfig: '/path/to/js',
      width: 561,
      height: 150
  };


   websiteApp.directive('ckEditor', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
          var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);
          if($scope.ckEditorConfig){
              $.each($scope.ckEditorConfig, function(key, value){
                  ck.config[key] = value;
              });
          }

          var height = ck.config.height; var width = ck.config.width;
          if(height && width){
              ck.on('instanceReady', function(event){
                  var editor = event.editor;
                  console.log('ck height: '+ height+', ck width: '+width);
                  console.log('editor config height: '+ editor.config.height+', editor config width: '+editor.config.width);
                  editor.resize(editor.config.width, editor.config.height, false, false);
              });
              // ck.resize(height, width, true, false);
          }
      }
  };
  ```

  }]);

and I have this in my html

```
> <textarea id="fflFieldLabel" class="txtArea" rows="1"
> ng-model="{{ngmodel}}" ck-editor></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`config.width`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-width) and [`config.height`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-height) it is not necessary to call [`editor.resize`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-resize), the size should be set according to the config automatically by editor itself on initialization.

It works with

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="1" cols="80">  
    <p>Foo Bar Baz</p>
</textarea>
```

and

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { width: 450, height: 150 } );
```

So maybe there is some integration issue, or dimensions is overwritten/updated somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<textarea id="fflFieldLabel" ></textarea>
     CKEDITOR.replace('#myfield',{customConfig :'',width:'700px',height:'700px'});
```

or change the width and height of the textarea tag. Hope it will work.

Comment: Nope that doesn't make any difference